# More remote debugging sessions for multiple instances of JBoss

Tags: jboss, remote-debugging, server-configuration

I'm running more instances of JBoss on one machine. 
This instances is created with own address binding parameter -b and runs on different configurations by -c parameter. 
The machine is Linux one and there are more virtual interfaces created (by ifconfig eth0:1 192.168.0.101 netmask 255.255.255.0 up).

My idea is that more people could run the JBoss in the its instance on one ip address and they will be able to test and debug code for their configuration.
But when I run JBoss in debug mode (to JAVA_OPTS added: -Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8787,server=y,suspend=n) the JBoss is listening on 0.0.0.0:8787 (got by netstat -avn). That means that the debug session is listening on all IPs of this machine - on all virtual interfaces. That what I don't want because when more instances of JBoss in debug mode is running I can't determine to which instance I'll be connected for debugging.

Is some possibility to say where the debug will be listening? Or am I able to restrict it somehow?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[you can set the IP which you want to be bind to](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/jpda/enhancements.html#machine-spec), and so it will be different to each VM:

```
-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=machine:port,server=y,suspend=n
```

Comment: Great, I'll try it. Thank you very much. I wasn't able to find it in the documentation. :)

Comment: @dadid,  may I ask you to have a look at a remote-debugging  related question here : tinyurl.com/ovglq92  ?